# how to delete testing library like com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.*, junit in release variant using proguard

Tags: android, proguard

I am using proguard, to obfuscate my app. I build app in release variant. when I decompile my apk, found Junit folder in it which is of no used, This Junit folder occupy 280kb which is quit large size for me. Is it possible to ask proguard to delete or not to use testing library like com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.* during release variant.
I tried with -assumenosideeffects on these libs but no effect.